# how to hide all <a> using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code,

```
<a id="save_11" onclick="updateData(this);"><img src='images/save.png' /></a>
<a id="save_12" onclick="updateData(this);"><img src='images/save.png' /></a>
<a id="save_23" onclick="updateData(this);"><img src='images/save.png' /></a>
```

How do I hide all `<a>` where it has ***save*** as a part of its id name.

Comment: Wouldn't class="save" make things easier?

Comment: i have provided an example of using class in my answer to hide it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use

```
$("a[id^='save']").hide();
```

it will hide all the anchors whose id starts with `save`

Answer (score 7):

```
$('a[id^="save"]').hide();
```

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Answer (score 4):

```
$("a").each(function() { 
    if ($(this).attr("id").indexOf("save") >= 0) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

or

```
$("a[id^=save]").hide();
```

As your comment says, however, if you can use classes, do so. It's faster, and looks cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a[id^='save_']").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('a:regex(id, save*)').hide()
```

should do the trick

but you need this: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("a[id^='save']").hide();
```

or

```
     $('a').each(function() { 
    if ($(this).attr('id').indexOf('save') >= 0) {
        $(this).hide();
    }
    });
```

refer http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1003-Cool-jQuery-Predicate-Selectors.htm

It is better to create a class and work on that to hide.

```
<a class="saveclass" id="save_11" onclick="updateData(this);"><img src='images/save.png' /></a>
<a class="saveclass" id="save_12" onclick="updateData(this);"><img src='images/save.png' /></a>
<a class="saveclass" id="save_23" onclick="updateData(this);"><img src='images/save.png' /></a>


$('.saveclass').hide();
```